# Making a complicated list comprehension conditional

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Here is my current one-liner:

```
leader = [server.get_member(x) for x in self.rosters[server.id][clan]['members'] if discord.utils.get(server.get_member(x).roles, id="463226598351699968")]
```

I want to only run this if `server.get_member(x)` is not `False`. How can I add this extra logic into this list comprehension? I understand how to do a basic `for` `in` statement, but nesting it deeper than that becomes a bit confusing for me.

Comment: please translate this in to a normal `for loop` for readability and for your own sake if you are the one who has to maintain this for the forseeable future

Comment: You should strive to write clean, maintainable code, not to cram everything into a single list-comprehension

Comment: Python list comprehensions are great for a lot of things but if you start getting lost in the logic its probably time to break it into a regular loop

Comment: Is this your API or someone else's - can you improve the decomposition? It might be better to have `server.get_member(x)` return `None` if there aren't any members. If `self.rosters[server.id][clan]['members']` is your own code, then decompose it better into something more OO.

Comment: One strong code smell that this requires for-loop/if-statements rather than a list-comprehension is that you're working around a clear need to have to **store state** by calling `server.get_member(x)` twice, as @blue_note said.

Answer (score 4):

In general, **do not sacrifice readability for the sake of writing a one-liner**. If it not immediately obvious how to do it with a list-comprehension, then use a for-loop.

```
leader = []

for x in self.rosters[server.id][clan]['members']:
    member = server.get_member(x)
    if member and discord.utils.get(member.roles, id="463226598351699968"):
        leader.append(member)
```

Although, in this specific case, since you do not need `x`, you can use `map` to apply `server.get_member` while iterating.

```
leader = [m for m in map(server.get_member, self.rosters[server.id][clan]['members'])
          if m and discord.utils.get(m.roles, id="463226598351699968")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The item in list comprehension can't be saved, so you'll have to evaluate it twice. Even if you could, **don't**. List comprehensions are for filtering, not for running code as side effect. It's unreadable and prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can achieve the effect of a temporary variable assignment with a nested list comprehension that iterates through a 1-tuple:

```
leader = [m for x in self.rosters[server.id][clan]['members'] for m in (server.get_member(x),) if m and discord.utils.get(m.roles, id="463226598351699968")]
```

But in this particular case, as @OlivierMelançon pointed out in the comment, since the additional assignment is simply mapping a value to a function call, you can achieve the desired result with the `map` function instead:

```
leader = [m for m in map(server.get_member, self.rosters[server.id][clan]['members']) if m and discord.utils.get(m.roles, id="463226598351699968")]
```

Answer (score -1):

While I agree with the comments suggesting you should not write this as a comprehension for readability you could try:

```
leader = [server.get_member(x) for x in self.rosters[server.id][clan]['members'] if discord.utils.get(server.get_member(x).roles, id="463226598351699968") if server.get_member(x)]
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15248356/6471039) answer.

Comment: This calls server.get_member three times.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely a really bad way to do it and that concerned me as I typed it.