# How to find if all values in a list of dicts are the same in Python, with exceptions

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list like:

```
statuses = [
    {
        "status": "active"
    },
    {
        "status": "active"
    },
    {
        "status": "active"
    },
    {
        "status": "active"
    },
    {
        "status": "unknown"
    },
    {
        "status": "none"
    },
]
```

How can I easily figure out, *while ignoring* the special values "unknown" and "none", whether all the *other* status values are the same?

I know I can [use all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666163) to find if all values are the same, but that doesn't let me take exceptions of this sort into account.

Comment: Normally I would propose to close a question like this because it can be straightforwardly broken down into a series of steps, all of which are matters of fundamental technique that are covered by existing duplicates. However, I can see at least two *fundamentally different ways* to decompose the task: by filtering out the "ignorable" values first and then checking if all remaining values are the same, or by making a tally of values and then discarding the tally for the ignorable values. It seems like both are covered by answers so far, too.

Comment: There's a subtlety here and I apologize if my edit got the wrong interpretation. If you want to know whether the non-ignored values match *a specific target value*, then that is the same as knowing whether *each* value is *one of* `{"unknown", "none", "active"}` - which is only trivially different from the problem you already know how to solve, and wouldn't merit a new question (you just need to express the logic for checking a single value against that set, and then use `all` the same way as before). So I assumed instead that you mean, are the non-ignored values *the same as each other*?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you assume correctly, indeed I am asking if the non-ignored values are the same as each other. Thanks very much for the edits and clarifying questions!

Answer (score 6):

Create a set of status values and check its length, excluding cases where the status is `'unknown'` or `'none'`.

```
len({d['status'] 
     for d in statuses 
     if d['status'] not in {'unknown', 'none'}
    }) == 1
```

You may wish to check that `'status'` is actually a key in each dictionary to ensure you don't get a `KeyError` in the process.

```
len({d['status'] 
     for d in statuses 
     if 'status' in d
     if d['status'] not in {'unknown', 'none'}
    }) == 1
```

Comment: Alternatively you could just create a full set and subtract `{'unknown', 'none'}` from it when done.

Comment: How in  the world does that double `if` block work in the second example? Never knew that worked like that? I would have thought you would need `and`

Comment: Just found my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248272/python-list-comprehension-with-multiple-ifs

Comment: @Jab the same way that nested `if` blocks would work in imperative code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18072759 for a more general approach to understanding list comprehensions; `if` clauses and `for` clauses can be freely mixed. (The Q&A you found also looks good.)

Comment: Could also have been `if 'status' in d and d['status'] not in {'unknown', 'none'}`

Comment: You could also prevent the KeyError with `d.get('status','none')` instead of `d['status']`.

Answer (score 2):

i think a very pythonic way to see whether the statuses are mostly active or inactive is to use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), as a bonus you know exactly how much each happened and you can report a sensible error, which will happen more than you think.

```py
from collections import Counter

statuses = [
        {
            "status": "active"
        },
        {
            "status": "unknown"
        },
        {
            "status": "none"
        },
    ]
counter = Counter((x['status'] for x in statuses))
if 'active' in counter and 'inactive' not in counter:
    print('active')
elif 'inactive' in counter and 'active' not in counter:
    print('inactive')
else:
    print(f'invalid state, found {counter.get("active",0)} active and {counter.get("inactive",0)} inactive.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension to filter out the entries you don't want, and then apply `all()` to that list:

```
filtered_statuses = [x for x in statuses if x['status'] != 'unknown' and x['status'] != 'none'])
all([x == filtered_statuses[0] for x in filtered_statuses])
```

Comment: Unfortunately `all()` will return `True` when given an empty list.

Comment: But I guess that doesn't matter, if you have an empty list you'll get an IndexError exception on `filtered_statuses[0]`.

Comment: @MarkRansom in fact there will not be an `IndexError` because that would require the indexing to be attempted, but starting from empty means there are no iterations. Also, `True` [*is the most reasonable result*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) for an empty list here. If every value is either `"unknown"` or `"none"`, then the condition "everything that isn't `"unknown"` or `"none"` is the same" *is met*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I wasn't arguing that `True` isn't a reasonable value for the empty list case, just that it probably wasn't what was desired by OP.  Good point about the IndexError though.